# Why don't we use an article before "Olivia" in "Olivia is an English teacher"?

Tags: articles, names

> Olivia is an English teacher. She is not working at present.

Why aren't we writing like this?

> The Olivia is an English Teacher

Comment: Do not use an article with a person's name. The exception occurs so rarely that I will not distract you with it.

Comment: Is your question specifically about why no definite or indefinite article is used if a person's given name or surname is either the subject or the (direct or indirect) object of the sentence? Or is your question meant to be broader? If it's the latter, please clarify the issue you're looking to address.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an article with a person's name. The exception occurs so rarely that I will not distract you with it. (Jeffrey Carney)

There is no real logic here. You just don't say "The Olivia", or "The she"

Comment: Well - there _is_ logic, as far as there ever is with language: a proper name usually designates an individual, so is already specific. Most languages I know follow that pattern, though some don't (Greek I think is different).

Comment: By "no real logic", I mean it could be a grammar rule that a determiner is always used with a proper noun. It would be equally logical, it's just not English.